# Different boxes for each modules inside sidebar module position

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've made a Joomla 2.5 template. You can have a look on this site: www.ranfar.com.

Have a look to the code of the sidebar. By now, I've something like that:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <!-- Here starts the first widget -->
    <h3>Widget title</h3>
    <ul>......... <!-- Module content --> ..........</ul>
    <!-- Here starts the second module -->
    <p>.... <!-- Second module content --> .........</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, I don't have a separate box for each widget. I would like to have something like the following:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <!-- Here starts the first module -->
    <div class="sidebar-module-box">
         <h3>Module title</h3>
         <ul>......... <!-- Module content --> ..........</ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Here starts the second module -->
    <div class="sidebar-module-box">
         <p>.... <!-- Second module content --> .........</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way I can style the class for module box.
How do I realize such a template? Where do I have to add it? This is the code I have in the index.php that generates the sidebar:

```
<?php if($this->countModules('ranfar-rightsidebar')) : ?>
    <div id="right-sidebar" class="float-right">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="ranfar-rightsidebar" style="sidebar" />
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution.

I had to open the file `/templates/THEME/html/modules.php`, where `THEME` is the name of my theme. There's a function like following:

```
function modChrome_sidebar($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
        <?php if ($module->showtitle) : ?>
            <h3><?php echo $module->title; ?></h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $module->content; ?>
    <?php endif;
}
```

I had to change it as follow:

```
function modChrome_sidebar($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
        <div class="module-box">
        <?php if ($module->showtitle) : ?>
            <h3><?php echo $module->title; ?></h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $module->content; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Now every module is enclosed inside a div with class "module-box".

Comment: You should select this as the correct answer. This is the standard way to control module chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla they're called modules (instead of widgets).  In your XML file you need to add the module positions, like this:

```
<positions>
    <position>login</position>
    <position>search</position>
    <position>sidebar1</position>       
    <position>sidebar2</position>
    <position>etc...</position>
</positions>
```

In your template then add each module position using the code you have above:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="sidebar1" style="xhtml" />
```

Wherever you have that Joomla will display the module in its place (next paragraph).  Quick note about "style" - you can make a [custom one or use one of the ones Joomla has already depending on your markup need](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_chrome)s.

Then, in the module manager, make a new module and select the position you want it to appear in.

Comment: Sorry, I called them widget but I know they're called modules. I already have both module position and module added in that position. My question was about enclose each module inside a div with a specific class that has to be the same for all of the module added in that position. Should I create a custom style for them?

Comment: Definitely, or you could use a template override for the module if you want to get it to do something different - they're really useful to play with: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core  and though outdated mostly still relevant and better explained: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides